# What is the difference between lazy loading Angular vs Traditional MPA?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

Currently my web site is developed using ASP.Net MVC a traditional MPA method. In order to improve performance i had come across Angular for SPA. However, after doing some research I found out that angular will load all component at initial time regardless the user need or not. Then i get to know lazy loading provided by angular which load the component when user navigate to the page. So want to ask if angular can do lazy loading what is the difference with traditional MPA? It seem like both is doing same thing when changing page and it load the necessary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, you are using jQuery in your project as one library.

Case MPA - Every time you navigate to another page this library gets loaded again along with all the other files which are already loaded. Example bootstrap, Some common CSS/JS files, images, etc (which definitely takes time to load).

Case SPA - Every time you navigate to another page only content is being loaded which are specific to that page example page-specific CSS/JS/Images not common libraries like jQuery/bootstrap etc because those are already loaded because Page is not being refreshed in this case. 
so, Eventually you saved lot of files to gets load again which definitely takes less time to render webpage.

Let me know if still unclear something.

Comment: but for MPA those common CSS/JS file is cache by my browser when first load. So when navigating it will not load those file again. Does it mean it is same with SPA?

Comment: okay but there must be some expiry of cache, also in case of SPA the time taken in the refreshing webpage is saved because in SPA the only view is being replaced with older one whereas in case of MPA whole web page is being rendered again, extra time is consumed by CSS parser JS parser.

Comment: Thank for your explanation, it help me a lot